# Internet browsing at work though remote proxy: what is leaked locally?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, ssh, proxy

Scenario: you set up a remote proxy (e.g. linode) and connect to it through ssh from your work pc.
You set up Chrome/Firefox to browse the internet through it (via socks5) instead of using the workplace proxy.

Is any information leaked locally? In other words, what can the workplace IT administrator see from the internet traffic? I am particularly unsure about DNS lookup and flash videos.

--

EDIT

With Firefox by default DNS lookup will be done locally and thus leaked. To change this you can type

```
about:config
```

in the location bar to access the advanced options. you need to set

```
network.proxy.socks_remote_dns = true
```

to resolve DNS queries on the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question!

I think **plugins can create connections that do not use the proxy configuration**. I've tested here with `iptraf` (`sudo iptraf -i eth0`) and lots of UDP packets appeared when I openned a *Google Hangout* (that uses a proprietary plugin) - I think it was used to send my camera stream.

For YouTube and Vimeo (using Flash Player on both), all the traffic pass through the proxy but for Grooveshark it seems that are some connections starting on ports `443` and `843` (I can't recognize which connections are) -- but they are not using too much bandwidth (all the music stream is passing through the proxy).

Maybe the "perfect" way is to change your system's route in a way your machine can only reach the SSH server (through your default gateway). So, even if a connection is made, it'll not have a route. Something like this:

```
sudo route del default
sudo route add SSH-server-IP gw your-gateway's-IP
```

Comment: the typical user system in the scenario above is a Windows PC without admin rights, not much chance to change settings :)